# Reading a file with n lines and printing number of completed lines

Tags: linux, bash, command

I am using following bash script to check for active hosts in the file ,

```bsh
echo "Checking for 200 status code.."
cat $1 | sort -u | while read line; do
    if [ $(curl -I -s "https://$line" -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}\n") = 200 ]
        then
            echo $line >> livedomains
    else
        echo $line >> otherdomains
fi
done < $1
```

The code is working fine , what I need is to print the number of checked lines(urls) after some time to notify the user regarding number of remaining lines(urls) to check.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: suppose there is 100 lines ( urls ) in the file that I am checking , I want to notify the user after an interval let it be 2 minutes regarding the number of lines or urls that have been tested so that the user will be able to understand the status of the testing

Comment: Maybe `wc -l livedomains otherdomains`? Depends if the output is okay for you.

Comment: that is somewhat ok , but it would better if I can notify with completed line number echoed in the terminal

Comment: Like `echo "completed: $(wc -l <livedomains)"` or for both files `echo "completed: $(cat livedomains otherdomains | wc -l)"`?

Comment: i will prefer second one , echo total number of lines completed , it has to be done at regular intervals say about 2 minutes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

# update status after step seconds or greater
step=5
count=0
echo "Checking for 200 status code.."
start=$(date +'%s')

sort -u "$1" | while read line; do
    http_status=$(curl -I -s "https://$line" -o /dev/null -w "%{http_code}\n")
    case "$http_status" in
        200)
            echo "$line" >> livedomains
            ;;
        302)
            echo "$line" >> redirecteddomains
            ;;
        *)
            echo "$line" >> otherdomains
    esac
    ((count++))

    now=$(date +'%s')
    if [ "$start" -le "$((now - step))" ]; then
        start=$now
        echo "completed: $count"
    fi
done
```

The update interval is set to 5 seconds, you can change it to 120.

**Edit:** I changed my mind and use a counter variable instead of `wc`.

Additional changes:

- added shebang `#!/bin/bash` in first line
- removed input `< $1` in last line (otherwise it's not sorted)
- added some quotes

Comment: can you edit the code such that if a 302 is found , strip the redirected location and save to redirecteddomains

Comment: Yes, I can change that. But what do you mean by "strip the redirected location"? Strip from what? And what about the other [status codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#3xx_Redirection) like 301 for example?

Comment: when you curl instagram.com which gets redirected with 301 , it will show results in the form of headers  like this `HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Location: https://instagram.com/
Content-Type: text/plain
Server: proxygen-bolt
Date: Sun, 25 Aug 2019 19:16:40 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
 `
 i will replace with 301 and other status codes depending on my need , i need to strip the location in the header from the result to another file

Comment: Ok, that's done! I thought you wanted to strip the domain from your input list or whatever ;) I changed the `if-else` statement to a `case` statement. If you want to add the 301 status, then change `302)` to `30[12])`. Or if you want all 30x status codes, then change it to `30?)`.